# Multiple <li> elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm making a site for my friend and I wonder if I could put two html `<li>` elements next to the each other? I've got a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thediex09/Ve8sn/1/).

Comment: do you want the to li in horizontal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set their display to `inline` or `inline-block`. OR You may float them left.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
li{display:inline-block;}
```

or

```
li{float:left;}
```

Comment: Just note that if you are using `float` make sure you clear them

Comment: Yes but if he doesn't know how to float, he will learn to use clearfix method after doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    <ul>
    <li class="main"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="main"><a href="#">Dropdown Goes Here</a>
        <ul>
        <a href="#" class="gr">Dropdown content goes here</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

add this to style

```
.main{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: You can not use multiple same id's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need it for `nav`, first, give body `width:100%;`

```
body {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#EBEBEB;
    font-family:Calibri;
    width:100%;
}
nav {
    width:100%; /* this will set nav full width of conatiner*/
}
nav > ul >li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%; /* this will put 2 in one row*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `float` for your elements, like this:

```
li{
    float: left;   /*  or right  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked. These do. Either:
If using Bootstrap 4, use:

```
<ul class="list-group">
```

Or:

```
<ul class="OnePerLine">

.OnePerLine {
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this :

```
li { 
   display: inline-flex;
   float: left;
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `float` property, like:

```
li{
    float: left;
}
```

or

```
li{
    float: right;
}
```